# pg_prepare and pg_fetch_object

Tags: php, postgresql

I am preparing a statement in php using the postgres extension.

Then I try to fetch the result as an object using `pg_fetch_object`.

No rows returned, from the prepared statement but it should.

I also get the following warning:

> **Warning**:  pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR:  prepared statement "parking" already exists in **C:\xampp\htdocs\map\MapMarkers.php** on line **33**

```
$devices_query = pg_query($conn, "SELECT applications.name category, devices.* FROM app_as.application applications, app_as.device devices WHERE applications.id = devices.application_id");

//variables are bound in the loop
$parking_pst = pg_prepare($conn, "parking", "SELECT distinct on (name) name,application_name,longitude,latitude,parking_car_status status,received_at FROM V_DEVICE_PARKING WHERE name = $1");



while ($devices = pg_fetch_object($devices_query)) {

        pg_execute($conn, "parking",[$devices->name]);

        while ($parking = pg_fetch_object($parking_pst)) {
            $devices->parking_car_status = $parking->parking_car_status;
        }

    $data['DEVICES'][] = $devices;
}
```

Comment: And what is unclear here?

Comment: Preparing and fetching, is what i am trying.It returns no rows but the warning in the yellow box.

Comment: Do you __understand__ what is written in the warning?

Comment: Yes, i dont know why it's showing. I deleted all lines of code but this. It's still showing this warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error/warning because you are calling `pg_fetch_object()` on the `pg_prepare()` call.  Essentially, every time you iterate in the `while()` loop, you are calling `pg_prepare()` again, inadvertently trying to create a new prepared statement called "parking."

What you really mean to do is to get the result of `pg_execute()` and then pull the results with `pg_fetch_object()`:

```
$devices_query = pg_query($conn, "SELECT applications.name category, devices.* FROM app_as.application applications, app_as.device devices WHERE applications.id = devices.application_id");

$prepare_result = pg_prepare($conn, "parking", "SELECT distinct on (name) name,application_name,longitude,latitude,parking_car_status status,received_at FROM V_DEVICE_PARKING WHERE name = $1");

// Maybe process $prepare_result as needed here

while ($devices = pg_fetch_object($devices_query)) {

        $execute_result = pg_execute($conn, "parking", [$devices->name]);

        while ($parking = pg_fetch_object($execute_result)) {
            $devices->parking_car_status = $parking->parking_car_status;
        }

    $data['DEVICES'][] = $devices;
}
```

Comment: It works only if i turn off warnings in PHP. I get `<b>Warning</b>:  pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR:  prepared statement &quot;parking&quot; already exists in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\map\MapMarkers.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />` Event if i don't execute it i get this error.